# In which ‘Space Patrol’ episode was Captain Dart attacked by a two-legged, horned creature?

Tags: tv, episode-identification

In the '60s I saw an episode of 'Space Patrol' - the first I ever saw - where Captain Dart is attacked and knocked down by a two-legged creature with a horn on its nose. For a puppet show it was pretty violent and it impressed me so much I became an instant fan.

I would appreciate it if someone could identify this episode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "[Husky Becomes Invisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Patrol_(1962_TV_series))".

Described [here](http://tvminus50.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/thursday-5-december-1963.html), the bipedal, horned creature that attacks Dart is an 'Aba Bird'

Comment: That is the one - thanks! But I never realized how dumb Captain Dart was - my respect for him has definitely dropped a notch.